# wanted to replace mask sensitive information ***** by using Regex

Tags: java, regex

For example : `<element name="XYZ" type="string">9032905776</element>`

In above regex we need to check whether the name attribute has value "XYZ" or not.

if name attribute contain "XYZ" then it should skip type="String" and mask 9032905776 as ***.

Expected Output:  `<element name="XYZ" type="string">***</element>`

```
final String expressionTemplate = "(?<=<element name=\"(?i:XYZ)\"[a-z?]>)(.*?)(?=</element>)";
System.out.println("Regex :"+expressionTemplate);
System.out.println("\nRequest Before    :"+dummy);
System.out.println("Request After   :"+dummy.replaceAll(expressionTemplate.toString(), "*****"));
```

out put :

Comment: Off-topic, but why `expressionTemplate.toString()` when `expressionTemplate` is already a `String`? Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) might be an enlightening (and memorable) read.

Comment: Note that regex cannot parse HTML/XML and requires a parser to do this properly.  You'll mangle the file in some cases if you do it this way.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: ignore that expressionTemplate.toString()

Comment: Are you certain that the `<element>` tag is the only tag whicb needs the replacement and that no other tags would be nested inside it?

Comment: input :<element name="MDN">458796</element> 
 (?<=<element name=\"(?i:MDN)\">)(.*?)(?=</element>) this expression is replacing and getting proper output is : <element name="MDN">******</element> 
But, 
for this input : <element name="MDN"  type="string">8805450294</element> 
OUt put is same :::::::::::::<element name="MDN"  type="string">8805450294</element>

Answer (score 0):

[Don't Parse HTML With Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

The problem is, no matter what regex we write, it would be easy to come up with a case where it doesn't work. Just imagine when special characters could be found inside `type="string"`.

Instead you should use a real Java HTML parser (for example, [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/))

---

However, if you want to disregard my warnings, and use a regex that could easily break on some unusual inputs, then try something like this:

```
final String expressionTemplate = "(?<=<element name=\"XYZ\"[^>]{0,99}>)(.*?)(?=</element>)";
```

**Known issues:**

- breaks if `>` appears in type="string"
- breaks if opening tag longer than specified amount (see hard-coded `99`)
- many other ways it could break... `<!--` HTML comments, etc.

Comment: String dummy1 = "<=asasa<element name=\"XYZ\">9032905776</element>";
  final String expressionTemplate = "(?<=<element name=\"(?i:XYZ)\">)(.*?)(?=</element>)";
  System.out.println("Regex :" + expressionTemplate);
  System.out.println("\nRequest Before    :" + dummy1);
  System.out.println("Request After   :" + dummy1.replaceAll(expressionTemplate.toString(), "*****"));

Comment: @NamburiManikanta what is the purpose of this comment? Did you read my answer?